# Rotate Vector By Vector

Tags: math, vector, trigonometry

[image]

As you can see on that picture i need to find _tPos vector position based on tPos vector relative to aPos Vector.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Can I say that you have points A, B, and C, and you want to find such point D that `length(C-A) = length(D-A)` and `length(C-B) = length(D-B)`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about trigonometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

If you denote the length of the purple line as `T`, then the corresponding rotation angle `phi` can be calculated as

```
cos(phi) = 1 - T^2/(2R^2)
```

Now, you need to rotate the red point with coordinates `x,y` by `phi` clockwise. The coordinates of the rotated point are thus:

```
x' =  cos(phi)*x + sin(phi)*y
y' = -sin(phi)*x + cos(phi)*y
```

Here, the value of `sin(phi)` can be expressed directly as:

```
sin(phi) = T/R * sqrt(1 - T^2/(4R^2))
```